# "Wrapper" TinyMce Custom Plugin

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Maybe you guys can help me. I am trying to create a custom plugin for TinyMce that basically wraps my selection like so:

`<div class="myClass" >` *content* `</div>`

Sort of like how the bold button works. I don't know a lot of javascript and the current plugins are really confusiong so im wondering if anyone can tell me how to do it. I have already created my custom plugin and made it show up on TinyMce, so that part is done, I just need the method.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I did it:

```
        this.editor = ed;

        ed.addCommand('mceblizzardquote', function () {

            var se = ed.selection.getContent();

            if (se.trim() == "") {
                alert("Nothing Selected.");
                return;
            }

            var s1 = '<div class="myClass" >';
            s1 += se + '</div>';

            ed.selection.setContent(s1);
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping a selection is not a big problem - in case your html root element is a `<p>`. Otherwise it won't work.

Here is the necessary code:

```
var ed = tinymce.get('my_editor_id');
var content = ed.selection.getContent();
tinymce.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<div class="myClass">'+content+'</div>');
```

Be aware that you might encounter problems when selection only parts of a paragraph.

Comment: This probably works too, but I did it in another way as listed below.